# How can a get value from each product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here…. I’m using the following to get the rate value of the first product. What I really want though is to get each product rate value in order to calculate the tax for each product? Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
product = Product.first
product.tax_rate.rate`
```

Thank you!!

**Update 1**

This is what I'm trying to do inside the order model:

```
def tax_amount
  amount*rates
end


def rates
   product = Product.all.find_each do |product|
   product.tax_rate.rate
   end
end


def amount 
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end


def total
    amount+tax_amount
end
```

end

[And I'm getting nothing under the tax amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DDE2.png)

The associations are:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :tax_category, :class_name => 'TaxCategory' 

  has_one :tax_rate, through: :tax_category, source: :tax_rate
  has_one :zone, through: :tax_rate, source: :zone 

class TaxCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tax_rate
  has_one :zone, through: :tax_rate, source: :zone 
  has_many :products
end

class TaxRate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :zone, :class_name => 'Zone'
  has_many :tax_categories
end
```

**Update 2**

[I'm getting an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGFWb.png)

now that I implement this :`Product.joins(:tax_rate).pluck('"tax_rates"."rate"')`

Comment: `Product.all.each`? But you may not want to do that if there are a lot of products--it depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: what is line_items ?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to get at. Are you just trying to get an array of all rates for all Products?

Comment: @jeffdill2...I'm trying to get the associated rate value for each product and calculate the total tax amount. I have a tax rate table: name:string, rate:decimal, zone:references that is associated with each product thru a tax category. You can view the associations above. That is 3 different models with appropriate associations.

Comment: Ah, and you're saying your associations aren't working correctly? i.e. `product.tax_rate.rate` isn't working correctly?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I understand your question now. You're trying to get the _total_ tax amount for your entire `products` table, based on the associated `TaxRate` and amount for each respective product. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jeffdill2 I appreciate it... The total tax amount for all the product on the order.

Comment: "all the product on the order" – I don't see any mention of an order in your question. Can you update it with any pertinent order info.

Comment: Sorry I meant "The total tax amount for all the products added to the order".. Products get added to cart and then end up in an order. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: So is there an `Order` model/association missing from your question?

Comment: @Theopap did you get your issue solved?

Comment: Yes I did @jeffdill2!!! I had to change the code a little bit around but all worked out fine. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to get the total tax amount for all of your `Product`s, this should work for you:

```
def self.total_tax_amount(order = nil)
  tax_amount = 0

  if order.present?
    order.products.find_each { |product| tax_amount += product.calculate_tax }
  else
    Product.all.find_each { |product| tax_amount += product.calculate_tax }
  end

  tax_amount
end

def amount 
  line_items.to_a.sum(&:total_price)
end

def calculate_tax
  amount * tax_rate.rate
end

# This will give you the total amount for the entire products table:
Product.total_tax_amount

# This will give you the total tax amount for a specific order:
@order = Order.first
Product.total_tax_amount(@order)
```

---

#### UPDATE #1

It sounds like you have an `Order` association to `Product`. I've modified the original code to either give you the total tax amount for the entire `products` table (if you don't pass any arguments) *OR* if you pass it an `Order` object, it'll only give you the total tax amount for the `Products` related to that `Order`.

Comment: Hmmm... now it's giving me an `undefined method total_tax_amount` on this line `Tax amount: <%= number_to_currency Product.total_tax_amount %>`

Comment: Restart your Rails server.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to achieve your goal. The most immediate is:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  product.tax_rate.rate
  # whatever
end
```

However, you will blow up your memory if your database contains a really lot of `Product` instances. In that case, you can do whatever you want to do, loading them in batches with [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each):

```
Product.all.find_each do |product|
  product.tax_rate.rate
  # whatever
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Bustikiller. I'm getting a blank space under the method. I have updated the questions so you can understand what I'm trying to do. Been trying to figure this one out for a while now, so I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck(column_name)`. It is the equivalent to do a simple `SELECT column_name FROM table`.

```
Product.joins(:tax_rate).pluck('"tax_rates"."rate"')
```

This works on postgres. The syntax may vary with your DB of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response @nicooga!! Hmmm weird... now I'm getting an array. I've uploaded a snapshot so you can see.

Comment: That line of code returns a list with the rate of each tax_rate associated with a product.